# How exactly works compiling Modules with makefile on linux?

Tags: makefile, module

Sorry for this question...I'm very nervous, because that...Maybe stupid.
Writing module for network management, installed linux/kernel-headers on virtualbox, for the test create Makefile for compile test-module.(How standart Hello world). In last time the same problems I don't have, so why asking question...

The code MakeFile:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
        obj-m := hello.o
else
        KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
        PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
endif
```

Console:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.18.0-kali7-amd64/build M=/home/matrix/Documents/renviroments/Drivers/Practice/Hello_Worlds modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali7-amd64'
  MODPOST /home/matrix/Documents/renviroments/Drivers/Practice/Hello_Worlds/Module.symvers
Error: not ELF
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali7-common/scripts/Makefile.modpost:134: /home/matrix/Documents/renviroments/Drivers/Practice/Hello_Worlds/Module.symvers] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali7-common/Makefile:1777: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali7-amd64'
make: *** [Makefile:7: default] Error 2
```

So, some questions:

1. What about mistake in this code?
2. Can you give any materials for the full understand work MakeFile-scripts and how they use Kernel-headers and other?

Again...Sorry for this question.

Comment: I don't understand why you set `KERNELDIR` in one part of your if-statement, and set `obj-m` in the other part.  Don't you need to set both these variables regardless of whether `KERNELRELEASE` is set or not?  You need to have _some_ file in your kernel module, after all.

Comment: Yeah, that's my uncompetision in this questions. I should stay question different: HOW WORKS make file for module in kernel-linux?
UPD: Problem maybe has on system level, because many of modules just now works, in the make file or outside of it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand most of that comment.  However, note that StackOverflow is limited to solving specific, technical problems.  It's not the right place to go to ask to have the entirety of a system like the kernel module build environment explained.  There is documentation to describe that.